# Electron example didn't work with "exited with signal SIGSEGV"

Tags: javascript, electron

i have a problem it didn't work Electron example app with

```
/home/jms08/jms08/Electroning/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGSEGV
```

I cloned the Electron-quickstart-example and
i didn't touch anything(node_modules downloaded)

Comment: This is probably more suited as an issue on GitHub with Electron itself. Without any more information, we can't help you here as it's not a code problem. [Please file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/new/choose)

Comment: thanks, i saw the github issue, WSL not supported.

Comment: So your problem is basically solved? Please answer your own question then (and accept that answer) so that other actually know that this is solved. Also, how does WSL fit into this question? You didn't mention anything in the original question (please include every detail in future questions!)...

Comment: StackMinsung0809,   can you share your solution. i am facing same issue